# Discord.js doesn't list Authorized channel/s

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to send a message using an Discord Bot that I have installed on a channel with all permissions possible. But when I try to fetch the channels or the specific channel with id it returns 'Unknown Channel' and If i fetch all channels i get a empty object with no channels on it, even i have authorized one, the same for users. The token is correct and the bot name it prints correctly but I'm missing something.

Here is my snippet:

```js
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse} from 'next'
import { Client, GatewayIntentBits } from 'discord.js'
import { Headers, Payload, PayloadCustom, Responder } from '@/utils'
// import { ErrorResponse, PromptNotGeneratedResponse, SuccessResponse } from '@/helpers'
import { PromptNotGeneratedResponse } from '@/helpers'

const SendMessage = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    try {
        const { bot_token, userId, message } = req.body

        await Headers(req, res)
        await Payload(req, res, bot_token, 'bot_token')
        await PayloadCustom(req, res, userId, 'userId')
        await PayloadCustom(req, res, message, 'message')

        const client = new Client({
            intents: [
                GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
                GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
            ]
        })

        client.login(bot_token)

        client.once('ready', bot => {
            console.log(`ready! logged in as ${bot.user.tag}.`)
        
            client.channels.fetch('id here')
                .then(channel => console.log(channel))
                .catch(console.error)
        })

    }

    catch(error) {
        console.error(error)
        Responder(PromptNotGeneratedResponse(res))
    }
}

export default SendMessage
```